# Collect2.exe [Error] ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: c++

I made a simple program

```
#include<iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

class x
{
    private:
        int y;


    public:
     x()
    {
        y=0;
    }

    void incrementy()
    {
        y=0+1;
    }

    void show()
    {
    cout<<("y is:"+y)<<endl;
    }

    int main()
    {
        x*showy = new x();
        showy->show();
        return 0;


    }

};
```

but when i compile i get errors such as:

```
C:\Users\Jevaughn\Documents\collect2.exe    [Error] ld returned 1 exit status
```

and

```
18 C:\crossdev\src\mingw-w64-v3-git\mingw-w64-crt\crt\crt0_c.c  undefined reference to `WinMain'
```

im not sure what these errors are referring to and how to resolve them. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: your main method is not supposed to be inside a class. are you coming from c# / java?

Comment: no references from either